# How to find number of pixels from specific color in an image?

Tags: c#, colors

So i'm trying to make a program that can find how many pixels of a specific colour it has in it. The images are pictures taken with camera and after that some areas on them has been marked on photoshop, and i need to find the exact number of this pixels. But i have few problems. 
I'm using getPixel(x,y) but and i'm comparing to the Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue) that i want but... my first problem is that for colors differ a little for example i want to find out the color
RGB 116,110,40 but when you draw with this color on photoshop some pixels get a little diferent color like RGB 115,108,38 (and others similar) and i want to include this as well. So i finally came up with this code(but it seems that id does now work right):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Bitmap image1;
    int count=0;
    int red, green, blue;
    int redt, greent, bluet;
    double reshenie;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            red = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            green = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            blue = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

                           // Retrieve the image.
            image1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\bg-img.jpg", true);
             double widht, height, pixel ;
            int x, y;
            MessageBox.Show(pixel.ToString());

            // Loop through the images pixels            
            for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    redt = pixelColor.R;
                    greent = pixelColor.G;
                    bluet = pixelColor.B;


                    if ((red+10>=redt) && (red-10>=redt))//i used +-10 in attempt to resolve the problem that i have writed about the close colours
                    {

                        if ((green + 10 >= greent) && (green - 10 >= greent))
                        {
                            if ((blue + 10 >= bluet) && (blue - 10 >= bluet))
                            {
                                count += 1;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = image1;

            MessageBox.Show("Imashe " + count.ToString());
            count = 0;

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error." +
                "Check the path to the image file.");

        }

    }
```

The problem is that i dont get the result that i expect. For example when i have to get like 1000 pixels i get more or less and i cant find where is my mistake. So if someone can give me idea what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I've posted an example on my blog that will return the location of each pixel in an image of a specified color. http://www.jarloo.com/find-all-pixels/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
if ((green + 10 >= greent) && (green - 10 >= greent))
```

If `(a - 10 >= b)`, then for sure `(a + 10 >= b)`. See if you can understand why.

I think you may have meant

```
if ((green - 10 <= greent) && (greent <= green + 10))
```

Ordering the condition like that helps with readability, because `greent` has to be *between* `green - 10` and `green + 10`, and is also physically located *between* those expressions.

Comment: Just for the record: I re-read your reply and your statement *If (a + 10 >= b), then for sure (a - 10 >= b). See if you can understand why.* is wrong. Example: `a = 0, b = 5: 0 + 10 is >= 5, 0 - 10  is not >= 5` I think you meant: *If `(a - 10 >= b)` then for sure `(a + 10 >= b)`*.

Answer (score 5):

Try with this loop instead :

```
int epsilon = 10;

for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; ++x)
{
    for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; ++y)
    {
        Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
        redt = pixelColor.R;
        greent = pixelColor.G;
        bluet = pixelColor.B;

        if (Math.Abs(redt   - red)   <= epsilon &&
            Math.Abs(greent - green) <= epsilon &&
            Math.Abs(bluet  - blue)  <= epsilon)
        {
            ++ count;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `epsilon` is the maximal difference between pixel color and targetted color, for each channel.

Answer (score 1):

I think your color comparison is not right. You mixed the `<=` and `>=` in your attempt to be in a range around the color. Try this:

```
if ((red+10 >= redt) && (red-10 <= redt)) //i used +-10 in attempt to resolve the problem that i have writed about the close colours
{
    if ((green + 10 >= greent) && (green - 10 <= greent))
    {
        if ((blue + 10 >= bluet) && (blue - 10 <= bluet))
        {
           count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help!!!  
I started to think i`m going crazy lol... it was working yesterday and now after few changes it stopped... 
Thank you one more time for your help!!!

Comment: Great we could help. Please remember to pick one of the answers and make it your accepted solution.